# Meteor client side sort Collection

Tags: mongodb, sorting, collections, meteor

I have a DrawingHistory collection which stores data to be used for redrawing canvas data, but I can't seem to find a way to sort the information by a time property. Here's my current function

```
DrawingHistory.find().observeChanges
  added: ( id , data ) =>
    @setupUserDraw data unless Session.equals 'user_id' , data.sid
```

Sometimes the order gets messed up, and I looked online for sorting where people say to do `DrawingHistory.find().sort( { time: -1 } )` but find() doesn't have a sort property. Any ideas where I'm off?

Comment: I have not tried, but in another similar question, someone suggest to use the underscorejs sort function. Clearly, the sort method in meteor still have something to fix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If my memory isn't failing me, this should do it, the first `{}` being the selector, the second `{...}` being the options.

```
DrawingHistory.find({}, {sort: {time: -1}});
```

EDIT: Found the [docs on find()](http://docs.meteor.com/#find).