# Meteor - How to specify fields to return AND sort?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor, mongodb-query

From the MongoDB [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#specify-the-fields-to-return), I know you can specify the fields to return using something like this:

```
db.products.find( { qty: { $gt: 25 } }, { item: 1, qty: 0 } )
```

And you can sort the rows using [`sort()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#order-documents-in-the-result-set)

```
db.bios.find().sort( { name: 1 } )
```

However, [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16862659/2317532) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13966922/2317532) on SO suggests this format:

```
DrawingHistory.find({}, {sort: {time: -1}});
Aphorisms.find({}, {sort: {date_created: -1}});
```

So I tried these, but none worked:

```
return Questions.find({}, {text: 1, options: 1}).sort({order: 1}); // Returns nothing
return Questions.find({}, {text: 1, options: 1}, {sort: {order: 1}}); // Doesn't work
return Questions.find({}, {sort: {order: 1}}, {text: 1, options: 1}); // Only first filter gets applied
```

Example document/row:

```
{
    "options": [
        {
            "answer": "Answer I",
            "value": "A"
        },
        {
            "answer": "Answer II",
            "value": "B"
        },
        {
            "answer": "Answer III",
            "value": "C"
        },
        {
            "answer": "Answer IV",
            "value": "D"
        }
    ],
    "order": 1,
    "text": "Question A"
}
```

### Question

**So, what is the correct way to specify fields to return *AND* sort at the same time in Meteor?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to use mongo shell API queries, which are somewhat different from the [Meteor find API](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find).  In Meteor, options are all passed in the second argument:

```
Questions.find({}, {
    fields: {
        text: 1, 
        options: 1
    },
    sort: {
        order: 1
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Spent an hour failing! I just assumed Meteor's find is the same as MongDB's find.

Comment: No probs!  The Meteor docs are pretty good - I think you can solve most problems by looking through them.

Comment: Yeah =_=, maybe I should look at the Meteor's docs before MongoDB's docs...first day using Meteor and love it! Trying to convince my boss it's great

Comment: Can you answer me one more question? Why is it that when I place the `sort` option before `fields`, the `fields` option is no longer in effect?

Comment: Hmm, no I can't.  I'm surprised by that behavior, to be honest!

Comment: Haha...it turns out I was stupid and messed up the curly brackets...everything works, internet not broken, the Sun still rises. Thanks for your insights and advice!